# Getting posts - speed issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the below code that is pulling through all categories - sub categories and the posts of the sub categories. Everything is pulling through perfectly and exactly how we need, however we have noticed it is very slow to load for some reason. Does anyone know why this could be? We are only bringing through post links and title, so not sure why this is loading so slow.

```
<?php   
    $taxonomy = 'categories';
    $postType = 'coverage';
    $terms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => 'term_id', 'parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page'   => -1, 'hide_empty' => false]);

    foreach($terms as $term){
        echo '<div class="location-category" data-aos="fade-up"><h3>' . $term->name . '<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-right"></i></h3>';
        $childTerms = get_terms(['taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'orderby' => 'term_id', 'parent' => $term->term_id, 'hide_empty' => false]);

        foreach($childTerms as $childTerm)
        {
            $posts = get_posts(array(
                'post_status' =>'publish',
                'post_type' => $postType,
                'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                        'terms' => $childTerm->term_id
                    ),),
            ));
?>
                <div class="category-subs">
                    <p class="category-tl"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-down"></i> <?php echo $childTerm->name ?></p>
<?php       foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="category-bl"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-right"></i> <?php echo $post->post_title ?></a>
<?php       } ?>
                </div>
<?php
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: How long is "Very Slow"? How much data are you talking about being "Pulled Through"

Comment: Not alot atall, only about 40/50 posts. It just freezes the page for a few seconds then all populates, very strange

Comment: How many (sub)categories do you have? Because it looks like you do a get_posts query for each of them, even when they don't have any posts ('hide_empty'=>false).

On another note, I don't think 'posts_per_page' should be in the tax query but that shouldn't affect anything as far as I know.

Comment: We only have 4 categories and 17 sub categories altogether, then 77 posts but only displaying post title. So not a lot atall

Comment: Queries in queries are slow. If possible create your own statement into ONE query using joins or whatever it needs.